# Dúvida em relação ao TextWatcher - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tudo bem? Estou tendo problemas com o TextWatcher. Tipo, eu criei dois "plainText" que batizei de "et_texto1" e "et_texto2", quando eu escrevo algo no "et_texto1" tem que aparecer a palavra "Prazer!" no "et_texto2" e quando escrevo algo no "et_texto2", tem que aparecer a palavra "Olá" no "et_texto1", porém do jeito que eu coloquei, fica dando conflito, alguém poderia me ajudar a corrigir esse problema? Segue o meu código logo abaixo!

````
    EditText et_texto1, et_texto2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et_texto1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_texto1);
        et_texto2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_texto1);

        et_texto1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                et_texto2.setText("olá");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        et_texto1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                et_texto2.setText("Prazer!");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Você está adicionando os dois `TextWatcher` ao mesmo `EditText`. O correto seria:

```
EditText et_texto1, et_texto2;
boolean ativa = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_texto1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_texto1);
    et_texto2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_texto1);
    et_texto2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        
            if (!ativa) {
                return;
            }

            ativa = false;
            et_texto1.setText("olá");
            ativa = true;
        
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    
        }   
    });

    et_texto1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!ativa) {
                return;
            }

            ativa = false;
            et_texto2.setText("Prazer!");
            ativa = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Outra coisa, veja que adicionei uma nova **variável** `ativa`.

Quando ela está marcada como `true`, nosso código não realiza a alteração do texto no outro `EditText`. O motivo é muito simples: Você entraria em um *loop* infinito sem essa variável. Veja bem, quando você digita algo no `et_texto2`, por exemplo, ele vai lá e altera o `et_texto1`. Essa alteração no `et_texto1` dispara uma nova alteração no `et_texto2`, e assim sucessivamente.